# rhel + disk util is very high , what is the impact for long term

Tags: linux, operating-systems, redhat-enterprise-linux, vmdk, block-device

we have backup server with rhel version 7.2

server is VM machine , and OS disk is VMDK disk

disk used space is around - 50% , and from smartctl we not see problem

as we can see from follwing details
the disk util is very high sometimes even reached 100%
we can see also high pressure from reading side

regarding the util values , we think disk cant be helthy for a long time when util is around `90%-100%`

but apprititae to get your feedbacks / notification about this

```
Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
sda               4.00     0.00 3197.00    3.00 45856.00    12.00    28.67     2.92    0.92    0.92    2.67   0.30  94.50
Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
sda              10.00    11.00 3160.00   51.00 57068.00   248.00    35.70     3.33    1.05    1.03    2.39   0.30  97.00
Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
sda               2.00    30.00 2988.00   62.00 71208.00   500.00    47.02     3.93    1.30    1.26    3.11   0.32  97.40
Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
sda              15.00    29.00 2777.00   36.00 67748.00   260.00    48.35     7.20    2.62    2.61    3.69   0.34  94.60
Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
sda              20.00     6.00 2648.00   18.00 79044.00   100.00    59.37     7.00    2.65    2.63    5.44   0.35  94.30
Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
sda              17.00    14.00 2173.00   23.00 60388.00   148.00    55.13     5.74    2.73    2.72    3.13   0.39  84.60
Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
sda              20.00     0.00 2164.00    0.00 68856.00     0.00    63.64     6.48    3.09    3.09    0.00   0.39  84.10
Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
sda              15.00     0.00 1817.00    2.00 62424.00     9.00    68.65     5.90    3.35    3.35    2.50   0.47  85.70
Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
sda              80.00     0.00 2772.00    0.00 74056.00     0.00    53.43     6.60    2.30    2.30    0.00   0.32  87.90
Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
sda              13.00     0.00 4049.00    0.00 103024.00     0.00    50.89    13.04    3.26    3.26    0.00   0.25 100.00
Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
sda              13.00     0.00 3274.00    8.00 82548.00    64.00    50.34    12.73    4.08    4.08    4.12   0.30  99.80
Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
sda              11.00     0.00 3006.00    2.00 105880.00     8.00    70.40     9.51    3.24    3.24    2.50   0.32  96.00
Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
sda              25.00     0.00 2587.00    1.00 92080.00     4.00    71.16     8.56    3.25    3.25    2.00   0.31  81.10
Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
sda              37.00     0.00 3472.00    0.00 108932.00     0.00    62.75    11.94    3.48    3.48    0.00   0.28  96.70
```

Comment: Maybe you are indexing all the partition. Did you check it? Check also which program/service is using the disk and probably the cpu too... and in this case if it is _self-indexing_ (I mean if the program is indexing its own files and databases... It will never exit/ finish)

Comment: what you mean about ? "Maybe you are indexing all the partition"

Comment: There are programs/service (e.g. [akonadi](https://userbase.kde.org/Akonadi)) that scan up to all the files of your drives to create and index to speedup future searches... You can set what/where to scan and where not. The worst case is when that kind of programs scan their own database (but it is rare) or if there are different programs that scan each other cache/databases...  Note `updatedb` scans only searching for files (not inside them), but you can have slowdowns if it scans directory with a lot of files. It should be able to notice circular paths. Start checking the process using disk.